# Using LINQ to pull out a list from a node

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following snippet of xml and I want to be able to pull out the "Field" element with the name elements "V" attribute == "gender". Then I want to return the "list_value" element so that I can then iterate over them and add them to an observableCollection for display in a dropdown... I have NOT been able to just retrieve the  for this condition... any ideas?

```
<Field order="8">
            <name V="gender"/>
            <data_type V="list"/>
            <req_or_optional V=""/>
            <list_value>
                <item0 V="F"/>
                <item1 V="M"/>
                <item1 V="U"/>
            </list_value>
        </Field>
<Field order="9">
        <name V="date_of_birth"/>
        <data_type V="string"/>
        <req_or_optional V=""/>
</Field>
```

I've started off with this query:

```
XElement gender  = justFields.Elements("name").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("V") == "gender").SingleOrDefault();
```

This just returns the "name" element...

Thanks very much!
Harold

Comment: It's not clear what you have tried to complete your task. And it's not clear what problem you faced. Please add some C# code

Comment: And what problems are you having with that query that you've written so far?

Comment: I wonder if checking `=="gender"` is what you really want there.  (I forget if C# will save you when make identity checks when you meant equality)

Comment: If you want the `Field` elements instead of the `name` elements then why are you asking for the `name` elements in your code?

Comment: I need to select the Field that has the attribute "V" set to "gender" for its "Name" element.. and then from that pull out the "list_value" list so I can add them to an observablecollection. There are about 2 dozen "Field" elements in the complete list, and I only want to select out the one that is named "gender" as shown above.

Comment: @AshbyEngineer Yes, and you solved that exact problem when you selected out `name` elements.  If you want the `Field` elements instead then select *those*, and solve the exact same problem in the exact same way, but for the elements than you actually want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var collection = xDoc.Descendants("Field").Single(elt => elt.Element("name").Attribute("V").Value == "gender").Element("list_value").Elements();
```

Then if you want to get only "M", "F" and "U", just add

```
.Select(elt => elt.Attribute("V").Value);
```

Comment: That did it! The main thing I overlooked was the .Elements() at the end of the expression... thanks!